# absolutely positioned a tag is hidden on mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

It may be a very simple problem but I can't seem to get it to work. I have a absolutely positioned a tag in my header which is hidden in mobile view. How to get it to show Up? the url is http://tinyurl.com/a8o5ge2 the link is the top login link (pro account).

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the top-right link was overflowing outside of .top-bar

```
.top-bar {
overflow: visible;
}
```

Unfortunately this uncovers your menu. Try moving your pro-login out of the nav.